# Magento Menu Navigation stops working on product page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, magento

When viewing the website on ANY page but a product view page. The navigation menu loads correctly at the top of the page.
http://www.supremerattanfurniture.co.uk/index.php/

BUT

When you view the product view page the menu then deforms and sits underneath itself rather than horizontally.
http://www.supremerattanfurniture.co.uk/index.php/rattan-cube-sets/rattan-garden-2-seat-cube-sets/maze-rattan-balcony-2-seat-cube-set-with-footstools.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your CSS. css conflict at your product page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you know if its coming from an extension or something? Is there anyway that I can find out?

Comment: Contact to your UI developer(Designer). They will guide you.